# Is there a way to add svg to my img tag? The svg will not show even thought the path to the svg is correct

Tags: reactjs, svg

[image]

This is the svg and below is a picture of the code. I use styled components. That is why my img tag is Image.

[image]

It's only displaying the alt text. I also use React

Comment: Please post code as text rather than images and can we have an [mcve] rather than just images please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [adding SVGs in React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) you need to use `import`/`require`.

> You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells webpack
> to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a
> file gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can
> reference in your code, e.g. as the src attribute of an image or the
> href of a link to a PDF.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png
function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}
export default Header;
```